# A method for Binary Tree in java

Tags: java

The method fill() is to fill all of the null TreeNodes within height level. But when I run this code, it throws NullPointerException and I don't know what's happening here.

```
public void fill() {
    int height = height(overallRoot);
    overallRoot = fill(overallRoot, height);
}

//Fill all of the nodes within the height level
private IntTreeNode fill(IntTreeNode root, int height) {
    if (height == 0) { //if reaches the max height, don't add any node
        return null;
    } else if (root == null) { //if do not reach max height and root is null, add a series   
                               //of new nodes until it reaches the max height
        return new IntTreeNode(0, fill(root.left, height - 1), fill(root.right, height - 1));
    } else { 
        root.left = fill(root.left, height - 1);
        root.right = fill(root.right, height - 1);
    }
    return root;
} 

//returns the height of a tree
private int height(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exception.

Comment: It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your first `else if`. You first establish that `(root == null)`, then you attempt to check the `left` and `right` of it, despite already knowing that it is `null` and therefore does not have a `left` nor a `right`.